# Multidimensional array PHP issue

Tags: php, arrays, xml

i have a problem with arrays.
Both of these [PARAM] arrays are in the same product.
I have a product feed which has parameters like this :

```
[PARAM] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [PARAM_NAME] => Povrchová úprava 
        [VAL] => Brus 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [PARAM_NAME] => Materiál 
        [VAL] => Nerez AISI 304 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [PARAM_NAME] => Glass t 
        [VAL] => 8-10 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [PARAM_NAME] => Gmax(kg)/2pcs 
        [VAL] => 45 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [PARAM_NAME] => Otvor ve skle 
        [VAL] => Ano 
    ) 
) 
[PARAM] => Array ( 
    [PARAM_NAME] => Značka 
    [VAL] => Nice 
)
```

I need to loop through these [PARAM]s and get [PARAM_NAME] x [VAL]

Is there a possibility to loop through these and put then into variables?

I do have this code right now :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($input) or die ("ERROR : Cannot create object");
$json = json_encode($xml);

$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

foreach($array['SHOPITEM'] as $products) {
    if(isset($products['PARAM'])) {
        foreach ($products['PARAM'] as $param){
            print_r($param);
        }
    }
}
```

which gives these results :

```
ZnačkaNiceZnačkaNiceZnačkaNiceZnačkaRollkitZnačkaNiceZnačkaKeyArray ( 
    [PARAM_NAME] => Materiál 
    [VAL] => Ocel 
) 
Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Tyče 
        [VAL] => Elementy 
) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Tvar 
        [VAL] => Čtvercová tyč 
) 
Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Povrchová úprava 
        [VAL] => Brus 
    ) 
Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Materiál 
    [VAL] => Nerez AISI 304 
) 
Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Glass t 
    [VAL] => 8-10 
   ) 
Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Gmax(kg)/2pcs 
        [VAL] => 45 
)
Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Otvor ve skle 
    [VAL] => Ano 
) 
Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Povrchová úprava [VAL] => Brus ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Materiál [VAL] => Nerez AISI 304 ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Otvor [VAL] => bez otvoru ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Použití zábradlí [VAL] => tribunové ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Povrchová úprava [VAL] => Barva ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Materiál [VAL] => Ocel ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Povrchová úprava [VAL] => Zdobený ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Materiál [VAL] => Ocel ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Značka [VAL] => Key ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Frekvence (MHz) [VAL] => 433 ) Array ( [PARAM_NAME] => Typ kódu [VAL] => Multi (fix/rolling) )
```

Could you please help me with this issue? :) Thank you very much

Example XML:

```
<SHOPITEM>
    <ITEM_ID>RX4</ITEM_ID>
    <PARAM>
        <PARAM_NAME>Značka</PARAM_NAME>
        <VAL>Key</VAL>
    </PARAM>
    <URL>https://umakov.cz/prijmac-dvoukanalovy-univerzalni-433-9-m-hz-5fb05561d0cda8001c87180b?utm_content=RX4&amp;utm_medium=heureka.cz&amp;utm_source=cpc&amp;utm_term=P%C5%99%C3%ADjma%C4%8D+dvoukan%C3%A1lov%C3%BD+-+univerz%C3%A1ln%C3%AD+433%2C9MHz</URL>
    <MANUFACTURER>UMAKOV</MANUFACTURER>
    <CATEGORYTEXT>Stavebniny | Ploty a pletiva | Brány a branky</CATEGORYTEXT>
    <PRODUCTNAME>UMAKOV Příjmač dvoukanálový - univerzální 433,9MHz, RX4</PRODUCTNAME>
    <PARAM>
        <PARAM_NAME>Frekvence (MHz)</PARAM_NAME>
        <VAL>433</VAL>
    </PARAM>
    <DELIVERY_DATE>2</DELIVERY_DATE>
    <IMGURL>https://media-server.sprinx.com/umakovEshop/image/nomenklatura-0100000000015195-1-rx4_nomenklatura-0100000000015195-1-rx4_original.jpg</IMGURL>
    <DESCRIPTION>Štvorkanálový prijímač KEY, pracovná frekvencia 433,9 MHz. Pracuje s plávajúcim aj pevným kódom. Příjmač dvoukanálový - univerzální 433,9MHz</DESCRIPTION>
    <PRICE>713.9</PRICE>
    <HEUREKA_CPC>5</HEUREKA_CPC>
    <PARAM>
        <PARAM_NAME>Typ kódu</PARAM_NAME>
        <VAL>Multi (fix/rolling)</VAL>
    </PARAM>
    <PRODUCT>UMAKOV Příjmač dvoukanálový - univerzální 433,9MHz, RX4</PRODUCT>
    <PRICE_VAT>863.819</PRICE_VAT>
    <WARRANTY>24</WARRANTY>
</SHOPITEM>
```

Comment: Whats all this `ZnačkaNiceZnačkaNiceZnačkaNiceZnačkaRollkitZnačkaNiceZnačkaKey`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly That looks like it's coming from the 1-dimensional params.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is like : ManufacturerNiceManufacturerNice.... (in czech, sorry :) )

Comment: @Barmar O yes, well spotted

Comment: Turning a `SimpleXML` object into JSON is not a good idea. As you can see, when there's a single child, it's turned into an associative array, but when there are multiple children it's turned into an array of associative arrays. I suggest you use the Simple XML accessors, they provide a consistent API.

Comment: These arrays are different dimensions, but i can't understand why... i'll update it with one XML item

Comment: @PeTr See my comment for the "why".

Answer (score 0):

With your xml content as an example, and doing like this

```
<?php
$response = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SHOPITEM>
    <ITEM_ID>RX4</ITEM_ID>
    <PARAM>
        <PARAM_NAME>Značka</PARAM_NAME>
        <VAL>Key</VAL>
    </PARAM>
    <URL>https://umakov.cz/prijmac-dvoukanalovy-univerzalni-433-9-m-hz-5fb05561d0cda8001c87180b?utm_content=RX4&amp;utm_medium=heureka.cz&amp;utm_source=cpc&amp;utm_term=P%C5%99%C3%ADjma%C4%8D+dvoukan%C3%A1lov%C3%BD+-+univerz%C3%A1ln%C3%AD+433%2C9MHz</URL>
    <MANUFACTURER>UMAKOV</MANUFACTURER>
    <CATEGORYTEXT>Stavebniny | Ploty a pletiva | Brány a branky</CATEGORYTEXT>
    <PRODUCTNAME>UMAKOV Příjmač dvoukanálový - univerzální 433,9MHz, RX4</PRODUCTNAME>
    <PARAM>
        <PARAM_NAME>Frekvence (MHz)</PARAM_NAME>
        <VAL>433</VAL>
    </PARAM>
    <DELIVERY_DATE>2</DELIVERY_DATE>
    <IMGURL>https://media-server.sprinx.com/umakovEshop/image/nomenklatura-0100000000015195-1-rx4_nomenklatura-0100000000015195-1-rx4_original.jpg</IMGURL>
    <DESCRIPTION>Štvorkanálový prijímač KEY, pracovná frekvencia 433,9 MHz. Pracuje s plávajúcim aj pevným kódom. Příjmač dvoukanálový - univerzální 433,9MHz</DESCRIPTION>
    <PRICE>713.9</PRICE>
    <HEUREKA_CPC>5</HEUREKA_CPC>
    <PARAM>
        <PARAM_NAME>Typ kódu</PARAM_NAME>
        <VAL>Multi (fix/rolling)</VAL>
    </PARAM>
    <PRODUCT>UMAKOV Příjmač dvoukanálový - univerzální 433,9MHz, RX4</PRODUCT>
    <PRICE_VAT>863.819</PRICE_VAT>
    <WARRANTY>24</WARRANTY>
</SHOPITEM>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

foreach ($xml->PARAM as $param) {
   echo $param->PARAM_NAME, ' / ', $param->VAL, PHP_EOL;
}
```

You obtain

```
Značka / Key
Frekvence (MHz) / 433
Typ kódu / Multi (fix/rolling)
```

From there you can create the variable you want I think.